# Difference between getElapsedTime() and getQTime() in solr for java

Tags: java, solrj

I'm using Solr for Java and want to know what is the difference between  `getElapsedTime()` and `getQTime()`, after optimization solr indexes I'm confused which one is for what.

```
   SolrServer solrObject = _JpaTemplate.getSolrServerForCore(Constants.SOLR_CORE1);
   UpdateResponse sorlResponse = solrObject.optimize();
   System.out.print(sorlResponse.getElapsedTime());
   System.out.print(sorlResponse.getQTime());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the QTime is the time it takes for the query to execute in Solr whereas the Elapsed Time is the total time taken including the transmission and serialization / deserialization of the results.